# do databases not exist under event stores (like kafka)? Do we not query data from databases anymore?

Tags: events, apache-kafka, task

Trying to understand event driven microservices; like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IR1NLfaq7PU&t=882s) video. It seems like the basic idea is "producers create tasks that change the state of a system. Consumers read all relevant tasks (from whatever topic they care about) and make decisions off that"

So, if I had a system of jars- say a red, blue, and green jar (topics). And then had producers adding marbles to each jar (deciding color based on random number, let's say). The producers would tell kafka "add a marble to red. Add a marble to blue... etc"
Then, the consumers, every time we wanted to count jars would get the entire log and say "ok, a marble was added to red, so redCount++, then a marble was added to blue so blueCount++..." for the dozens/hundreds/thousands of lines that the log file takes up?

That can't be correct; I know it can't be correct. It seems incredibly inefficient; almost anti-efficient!

What am I missing in my knowledge of kafka tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in each of those topics will be retained as per a property `log.retention.{hours|minutes|ms}`. At the Kafka server level, this is set to 7 days by default for all topics. You could change this at a topic level as well.

In such a setting, a consumer will not be able to read the entire history if it needed to, so in this instance typically a consumer would:

1. consume the message i.e. "a marble no. 5 was added to red jar" at offset number 5
2. carry out the increment step i.e. `redCount++` and store the latest information (`redCount = 5`) in a local state store
3. Then commit the offset back to Kafka telling that it has read the message  at offset number 5
4. Then, just wait for the next message...

If however, your consumer doesn't have a local state store - In this case, you would need to increase the retention period i.e. `log.retention.ms=-1` to store the data forever. You could configure the configure the consumers to store that information locally in memory but in the event of failures there would be no choice but for the consumers to read from the beginning. This I agree is inefficient.

Comment: this is helpful. I guess kafka is designed more for a "stateless" system? Something more concerned with processing tasks (like a PDF to text service that uses OCR) rather than storing data (upload and save a PDF)

Comment: Well. This is an interesting point. The video you've highlighted in your post is typically about stateless microservices. However, Kafka can be used for stateful operations as well - there are reference case studies out there that have shared their experiences. Would you like to start a new post with your specific case and it might be easier to share details there perhaps?

Comment: Hah, I don't have a specific case; just trying to learn more! Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Understood. Then, I would recommend looking at a case study of New York times as I learnt this a while back that they store their news articles from 1850s in their Kafka cluster. There are more examples of Kafka being used as the single source of truth in an organisation. We may even see a feature in Kafka later on to carry out a key based fetch as well and Kafka may start competing with DBs... Who knows..! :D

Comment: This answer doesn't really address compacted topics

Comment: I did actually think of adding it but then chose to avoid it as I figured that the question was more around the inefficiency of having to read the logs should anything go wrong on the consumer's side. Also, I felt that in scenarios where the producers don't embed a key - typically the case when the producers are third party products rather than custom written code. If the key is left blank then the compaction will not really help.

Comment: But thanks for your feedback and answer. I'll make sure I keep these things in mind for future. :)

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Streams does use databases that can be queried, specifically RocksDB, although the interface is pluggable, it's not recommended to be used with external networked databases

In your example, if you emit events into some topic

```
(red, 1)
(blue, 1)
(green, 2)
(green, -1)
```

You can derive a table from consuming all those events to build a *stateful* representation of the totals

```
(red, 1)
(blue, 1)
(green, 1)
```

If you build a *compacted topic* of the totals after each individual add/remove, then you can persist the final state of each color at any moment in time, with each new color key overriding previously known state. If you wanted to completely remove a color from the state, you'd send a null value for that color

You can also expand this example using windowing to calculate the rate of adding each color over time, or the most popular recent color (think, trending topics)

You can see some really interesting applications/calculations [in this KSQL blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/taking-ksql-spin-using-real-time-device-data/)